# Distance between two lines

Tags: awk, distance

I have a set of points for which I need to calculate the distance between lines. 
Especially for the range 70:80. Can it be possible via awk ? or any other method

sample data

```
70.9247  24 
73.6148  24  
70.9231  25   
73.6144  25   
70.9216  26   
73.6141  26   
70.9201  27   
73.6138  27   
70.9187  28   
73.6136  28
```

Few points

1) Data sorted on y. So each value of y has 2 points.

2) I want the distance between x points for every y. i.e. y(new) = y(n+1)-y(n)

expected output:

```
2.6901 24
2.6912 25
...........




2.6949  28
```

[image: image is here]

thanks

Comment: What is the source ?

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek set of data points(.txt file)

Comment: Please, post some sample data in text with the expected output.

Comment: What is the way do you expect we will parse a png ?

Comment: Is this the distance between corresponding `x` values for the same `y`? Or is it more tricky than that.

Comment: @JNevill yes, its the distance between x values for the same y values.

Comment: Yes it's possible. In fact it's almost certainly trivial depending on what your input looks like. See [ask] for how to get a more detailed answer to your question and pay particular attention to the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: @EdMorton Updated with more information.

Comment: So, what is the expected output for that sample data?

Comment: @mathle you're getting closer to having asked a question - now provide the missing expected output given the input you posted and all that will be left to show us is what you've tried so far. Again, see [ask]...

Comment: @EdMorton expected output updated.

Comment: Explain why you only want 3 lines of data and a bunch of dots in your output given that input. If that's not what you want - make sure the expected output you provide is **the expected output** given the input you provide. The more effort you put into asking a question the more people will try to help you and the more likely you are to get the right answer. One more time - see [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is something like:

```
awk 'NR%2{t=$1;next}{print $1-t,$2}'
```

This does something like:

- If the record/line number `NR` is an odd number, store the value of the first field in `t` and skip to the next record/line
- Otherwise, print the expected output.

A similar way of writing this is:

```
awk '{if(NR%2){t=$1}else{print $1-t,$2}}'
```

but this is less awk-ish!